# Perfrom awk on every file in a current directory?

Tags: bash, awk

I have 44 files in a current directory and I can perform this operation on one of them:

```
awk '(NR>1) && ($29 <= 0.05 ) ' Stomach.v7.egenes.txt > Stomach.v7.egenes.txtE
```

file names look like this:

```
Adipose_Subcutaneous.v7.egenes.txt                   Brain_Putamen_basal_ganglia.v7.egenes.txt          Muscle_Skeletal.v7.egenes.txt
Adipose_Visceral_Omentum.v7.egenes.txt               Brain_Spinal_cord_cervical_c-1.v7.egenes.txt       Nerve_Tibial.v7.egenes.txt
```

so they all end with .v7.egenes.txt

I tried to make a loop and do this on all 44 files:

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.v7.egenes.txt
do 
awk '(NR>1) && ($29 <= 0.05 ) ' $f.v7.egenes.txt > $f.v7.egenes.txtE 
done
```

But I am getting these errors for all 44 files:

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file `Spleen.v7.egenes.txt.v7.egenes.txt' for reading (No such file or directory)
awk: fatal: cannot open file `Stomach.v7.egenes.txt.v7.egenes.txt' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

I should mention that all these files are in the current directory. What might be the issue?

Comment: just change `$f.v7.egenes.txt` into `"$f"`. `f` already has the `.v7.engenes.txt` part

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me, I tried this: awk '(NR>1) && ($29 <= 0.05 ) ' $f > $f"E"  but I am getting empty .txtE files in result. This should not be the case because they are lines which satisfy this criterium $29 <= 0.05

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing OP's issue with `for` loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.v7.egenes.txt
do 
   awk '(NR>1) && ($29 <= 0.05 )' "$f" > "temp_file" && mv "temp_file" "$f"
done
```

***Issue's fixed in OP's attempt:***

- File name was wrong which was passed to `awk` command, since `$f` itself will have complete file name we need not to add `.v7.egenes.txtE`  in their names.
- I am taking output of `awk` command into a temporary file named `temp_file` and then again renaming it to actual Input_file passed name, since it is not recommended to directly use `> $f` to same file name.

---

---

IMHO it is not recommended to use a for loop and then call an `awk` inside it, since `awk` could read multiple files by itself.

In case you have latest version of GNU awk could you please try following then.

```
gawk -i inplace '(NR>1) && ($29 <= 0.05 )' *.v7.egenes.txt
```

In case you want to take backup of all files and then edit them then try:

```
gawk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak '(NR>1) && ($29 <= 0.05 )' *.v7.egenes.txt
```

Comment: for loop did work this time. Can you please just confirm does the your for loop modifies files in place?

Comment: @anamaria, yes it should work why because `awk '(NR>1) && ($29 <= 0.05 )' "$f" > "temp_file" && mv "temp_file" "$f"` I am getting results into a temp_file and later I am renaming that temp_file to Input_file again, lemme know please in case of any queries and how your test goes?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '(NR>1) && ($29 <= 0.05 ) { print > FILENAME "E" }' *.v7.egenes.txt
```

Comment: IMHO, though OP's attempt shows character E in code but OP's comments let me also know that modifications should be saved into file itself, just thought to let you know on this one :) cheers.